# VS Code extension: setting custom semantic token colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to modify the styling of semantic token modifiers received from LSP
inside an extension without the need to create custom themes?

I am able to use `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` in my `settings.json` file and add the custom rules I want, but this setting is not available for `configurationDefaults` in the `package.json` file for a VS Code extension.

So the following snippet does work in `settings.json`, while the same does not work in `package.json` for an extension under the `configurationDefaults` field.

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
  "enabled": true,
  "rules": {
    "*.declaration": {
      "bold": true
    },
    "*.definition": {
      "italic": true
    },
    "*.readonly": "#ff0000"
  }
}
```

Is there another way?

Ideally, I would like to change both token types and token modifiers
for the language I introduce with the extension, but I don't want to create custom themes a user would need to use to get proper highlighting.

**Note:** I am forced to stick with the token types and modifiers supported by the language-client provided by Microsoft. Those are defined in the [LSP specification](https://microsoft.github.io//language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#textDocument_semanticTokens).

**Edit:** I use LSP with semantic tokens to get the token types and modifiers of a file. This should be similar to using TextMate grammar.
The problem I have, is applying correct styling/highlighting to those tokens. Since the language client limits the usable tokens, I apply a mapping between tokens of my language and the default LSP ones.

Meaning: token modifier `declaration` is in fact `bold` in my markup language

Comment: Im not really sure what your asking. To be blunt, I dont care what your forced to do, just please clearly state your question. And please provide an example of what you mean, even if it is a verbal example with no code.

Comment: I added rules that work in `settings.json`. Not sure how I can clarify my question further. Hope this helps.

Comment: If all this is for adding support to VS Code for a language, then you need a grammar. It sounds like your trying to create a language. Whether your writing your own, or adding support for a small, lesser known language, the place to start with every language that has ever exsisted is with a grammar. I think thats why your so confused. Semantic tokens are customized and modified using the tokens for a language which are defined by the languages grammar. VSCode uses TextMate grammars, but typically those grammars are created from a standard, or a pre existing grammar.

Comment: If your language already has a grammar introduce that, if not, then its pretty typical to start with a Backus Naur grammer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form You will also need a lexer or parser or both.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I do already have parsing setup and use LSP with semantic tokens. So I have the token types and modifiers as you would get by using TextMate grammars, but now I would like to properly highlight them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can introduce all your custom semantic tokens without the need to restrict yourself to the built-in ones. Personally I prefer the way proposed in the official sample file:
[semantic-tokens-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/semantic-tokens-sample/src/extension.ts).

As for the styling, you can easily modify an extension incl. semantic token colors via the package.json file as follows.

```
{
    ...
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true, // not necessary, just make sure it is not disabled
    "contributes": {
        "semanticTokenTypes": [ // not necessary if you use own parsing with "DocumentSemanticTokensProvider"
            {
                "id": "myToken",
                "superType": "myToken",
                "description": "myToken"
            }
        ],
        "configurationDefaults": {
            "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
                "rules": {
                    "comment": "#969896",
                    "string": "#B5BD68",
                    "myToken": "#323232" // custom
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For that I personally introduced myToken in the legend in an extension.ts file.

To check if your semantic token logic is working, you can use the
**[view/Command Palette/>Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens ans Scopes]** functionality that will reveal what semantic scope is attached to your keyword, if any.

If the provided code is not working for you, check your package.json and make sure the language settings are all correct:
settings that could be of relevance for you:

```
{
    ...
    "activationEvents": ["onLanguage:myLanguage"], // make sure your extension is activated
    "contributes": {"languages": [{"id": "myLanguage", "extensions": [".myLang"], "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"}]}
}
```

Furthermore check if your User / Workspace settings are interfering with your package.json settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My fault was in the contributes section of package.json. Taking your example as reference, I was able to achieve what I wanted.
Due to the restriction of the language-client package, I am not able to add custom tokens, but I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.